# How to get biggest value from 2 or more fields in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with customers that I join with a fact table with sales, based on invoices.

What I need from my report is to get in first part the biggest value of sales based on the incoming order type (1,2,3,C,D) for a customer for last year. And in the second part to get the same but for current year. What I get as result from my current query is all incoming order types with the customer revenue made for each of them. I tried with outer apply as subquery to get only the top 1 value ordered by revenue descending, but in the result I get the same - For all order types the customer revenue. Please help! I hope my explanation isn't understood only by me (happens a lot..)

```
  use dwh01;
WITH OrderTypeUsedLY AS
(
SELECT 
     c.CustomerKey
    ,c.BranchId
    ,c.CustomerId
    ,c.CustomerName
    ,ISNULL(SUM(y.[Sale_Revenue]), 0) as [Sale_Revenue_LY]
    ,ISNULL(SUM(y.[Sale_GrossMarginTotal]), 0) as [Sale_GrossMarginTotal_LY] 
    ,y.IncomingOrderTypeId as IncomingOrderType_LY
FROM live.DimCustomer c
left join (SELECT s.CustomerKey,iot.IncomingOrderTypeid, s.[Sale_Revenue], s.[Sale_GrossMarginTotal] FROM [dwh01].[live].[FactSales] s 
inner join live.DimDate d
    on d.DateId = s.PostingDateKey
inner join live.DimIncomingOrderType iot on iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey = s.IncomingOrderTypeKey
where s.ReportCurrencyId = 'LC'      
and D.Year = YEAR(GETDATE())-1   --- Last Year            
) y on c.CustomerKey = y.CustomerKey             
where c.CustomerKey = '157053'
group by c.CustomerKey, c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName, c.BranchId, y.IncomingOrderTypeId
),
--*********************************************************************************************************************************--
OrderTypeCY as(
SELECT 
     c.CustomerKey
    ,c.BranchId
    ,c.SalesRepKey
    ,c.CustomerId
    ,c.CustomerName
    ,ISNULL(SUM(y.[Sale_Revenue]), 0) as [Sale_Revenue_CY]
    ,ISNULL(SUM(y.[Sale_GrossMarginTotal]), 0) as [Sale_GrossMarginTotal_CY] 
    ,y.IncomingOrderTypeId as IncomingOrderType_CY
FROM live.DimCustomer c
left join (SELECT s.CustomerKey,iot.IncomingOrderTypeid, s.[Sale_Revenue], s.[Sale_GrossMarginTotal] FROM [dwh01].[live].[FactSales] s 
inner join live.DimDate d
    on d.DateId = s.PostingDateKey
inner join live.DimIncomingOrderType iot on iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey = s.IncomingOrderTypeKey
where s.ReportCurrencyId = 'LC'      
and D.Year = YEAR(GETDATE())   --- Current Year           
) y on c.CustomerKey = y.CustomerKey             
where c.CustomerKey = '157053'
group by c.CustomerKey, c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName, c.BranchId, y.IncomingOrderTypeId, c.SalesRepKey
)
--*********************************************************************************************************************************--
SELECT
    otly.BranchId,
    rep.SalesRepId,
    rep.SalesRepName,
    otly.CustomerId,
    otly.CustomerName,
    otly.Sale_Revenue_LY,
    otly.Sale_GrossMarginTotal_LY,
    IncomingOrderType_LY,
    otcy.Sale_Revenue_CY,
    otcy.Sale_GrossMarginTotal_CY,
    IncomingOrderType_CY
from OrderTypeUsedLY otly
left join OrderTypeCY otcy 
    on otly.CustomerKey = otcy.CustomerKey 
join live.DimCustomer cus on cus.CustomerKey = otcy.CustomerKey
join live.DimSalesRep rep on rep.SalesRepKey = otcy.SalesRepKey
order by otcy.Sale_Revenue_CY desc, otly.Sale_Revenue_LY desc
,rep.SalesRepId
```

And here is the outer apply I tried:

```
outer apply (
        SELECT top 1
    iot.IncomingOrderTypeId,
    Sale_Revenue
    FROM [dwh01].[live].DimIncomingOrderType iot
    where iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey = y.IncomingOrderTypeKey
    order by Sale_Revenue desc) x
```

In the first select ( with OrderTypeUsed_LY ) I get this:

[image: First part of query]

And I get the same in the second select, but with the values for current year.

The purpose of the report is to see the difference in the incoming order type most used (most profit made with it) for a customer last year and to see if he continues to use it this year, or uses another incoming order type this year.

Again I'm sorry for the bad explanation, I'm trying my best (I understand myself very well)

Here is the expected result:
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42SrB.png)

I marked in red the last year part and in green the current year part.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since this is a SQL Server question. They are not the same.  Also, please provide sample data and your expected results in text format.

Comment: I added expected result as screenshot of excel table, i hope it does the job! :)

Comment: outer apply is similar to an outer join in that it wont filter out any records.

Comment: Question: The second GROUP BY (Current Year) has a SalesRepKey field, missing in the first GROUP BY (Last Year). Is that correct?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is with using row_number() function in the inner query of the first CTE:

```
    (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by x0.CustomerKey order by x0.Sale_Revenue desc) as rn
    from 
        (
        select fs.CustomerKey, iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey,
        sum(fs.Sale_Revenue) as Sale_Revenue
        FROM [dwh01].[live].DimIncomingOrderType iot
        join live.FactSales fs 
        on iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey = fs.IncomingOrderTypeKey
        join live.DimDate d
        on d.DateId = fs.PostingDateKey 
        where d.[year] = @CurrentYear
        GROUP BY fs.CustomerKey, iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey
        ) as x0
) as x1 on x1.CustomerKey = s.CustomerKey
```

The row_number() function gets only the first row from the result for each customer, and that is with the biggest sale revenue ( order by sale_revenue desc).

Answer (score 0):

If you change the subquery to:

```
     SELECT
    iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey,
    MAX(Sale_Revenue)
    FROM [dwh01].[live].DimIncomingOrderType iot
    GROUP BY iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey
```

then you can JOIN (not APPLY) directly on IncomingOrderTypeKey AND Sale_Revenue.

Comment: Since the sale_revenue isnt in the same table as incoming order type(dimension), but in fact i made the subquery like this:
`SELECT
    iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey,
    MAX(fs.Sale_Revenue) as Sale_revenue
    FROM [dwh01].[live].DimIncomingOrderType iot
 join live.FactSales fs on fs.IncomingOrderTypeKey = iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey
    GROUP BY iot.IncomingOrderTypeKey` 
But the end result was the same, a row for each incoming order type and the revenue made, not only 1 row with the most revenue made.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
USE dwh01;

DECLARE @CustomerKey        varchar(6)  =   '157053'
    ,   @ReportCurrencyId   varchar(2)  =   'LC'
    ,   @CurrentYear        int         =   YEAR(GETDATE())
    ,   @TargetYear         int         =   YEAR(GETDATE())-1
;

WITH FactsTable AS
    (
        SELECT 
                        s.CustomerKey
                    ,   i.IncomingOrderTypeid
                    ,   [Sale_Revenue]          =   ISNULL(s.[Sale_Revenue]         , 0)
                    ,   [Sale_GrossMarginTotal] =   ISNULL(s.[Sale_GrossMarginTotal], 0) 
                    ,   d.[Year]

        FROM            [dwh01].[live].[FactSales]  s 
            inner join  live.DimDate                d   on  d.DateId                =   s.PostingDateKey
            inner join  live.DimIncomingOrderType   i   on  i.IncomingOrderTypeKey  =   s.IncomingOrderTypeKey
        where   
                        s.CustomerKey       =   @CustomerKey
                and     s.ReportCurrencyId  =   @ReportCurrencyId
    )
,   OrderTypeTable
    (
        SELECT 
                        c.CustomerKey
                    ,   c.BranchId
                    ,   c.CustomerId
                    ,   c.CustomerName
                    ,   c.SalesRepKey
                    
                    ,   IncomingOrderType_LY        =   SUM(CASE WHEN y.[Year] = @TargetYear    THEN y.IncomingOrderTypeId      ELSE 0 END)
                    ,   [Sale_Revenue_LY]           =   SUM(CASE WHEN y.[Year] = @TargetYear    THEN y.[Sale_Revenue]           ELSE 0 END)
                    ,   [Sale_GrossMarginTotal_LY]  =   SUM(CASE WHEN y.[Year] = @TargetYear    THEN y.[Sale_GrossMarginTotal]  ELSE 0 END)
                    
                    ,   IncomingOrderType_LY        =   SUM(CASE WHEN y.[Year] = @CurrentYear   THEN y.IncomingOrderTypeId      ELSE 0 END)
                    ,   [Sale_Revenue_CY]           =   SUM(CASE WHEN y.[Year] = @CurrentYear   THEN y.[Sale_Revenue]           ELSE 0 END)
                    ,   [Sale_GrossMarginTotal_CY]  =   SUM(CASE WHEN y.[Year] = @CurrentYear   THEN y.[Sale_GrossMarginTotal]  ELSE 0 END)

        FROM            live.DimCustomer    c
            left join   FactsTable          y   on  y.CustomerKey   =   c.CustomerKey

        group by    
                    c.CustomerKey
                ,   c.BranchId
                ,   c.CustomerId
                ,   c.CustomerName
                ,   y.IncomingOrderTypeId
                ,   c.SalesRepKey
    )

SELECT
        O.BranchId
    ,   R.SalesRepId
    ,   R.SalesRepName
    ,   O.CustomerId
    ,   O.CustomerName
    ,   O.Sale_Revenue_LY
    ,   O.Sale_GrossMarginTotal_LY
    ,   O.IncomingOrderType_LY
    ,   O.Sale_Revenue_CY
    ,   O..Sale_GrossMarginTotal_CY
    ,   O.IncomingOrderType_CY

from    OrderTypeTable      O
join    live.DimSalesRep    R   on  R.SalesRepKey = O.SalesRepKey
order by 
        O.Sale_Revenue_CY desc
    ,   O.Sale_Revenue_LY desc
    ,   R.SalesRepId
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, iam having trouble with the IncomingOrderType_LY/CY in ordertypTable, beacuse the column is varchar it gives error and i tried to cast as int but that didnt work, because there are strings in the column (order type D, C), can you suggest what to do? ,  ` IncomingOrderType_LY        =   SUM(CASE WHEN y.[Year] = @TargetYear    THEN y.IncomingOrderTypeId      ELSE 0 END)` .And maybe this wont work,because 1 customer could have used more than 1 incoming order type, and what i need is the incoming order type with most revenue.

Comment: Replace ELSE 0 with ELSE ''. And remember to vote please.

Comment: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.
I found another solution with row_number(), ill post it.